# Shake detection with using IBuilder or Load View without IBuilder

Tags: iphone, view, controller, shake, motion-detection

I am writing some application (let's say game - 1 view no cocoa controls) which needs to detect shakes.
As beginner with IOS have started with default openGL template (new one). Application works.

I have decided to add shakes. "motionBegan" don't work on "EAGLEview", so I have created view controller. Touches worked but "motionBegan" still not worked. (same like "viewDidAppear")

I thought that somehow IBuilder file is overlapping it.
So I have decided to resign from my IBuilder file and move forward without.

What I have now is:

main.m

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"SimplePianoAppDelegate");
```

SimplePianoAppDelegate.m

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[window setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];


viewController = [[InputControler alloc] init];
glView=[[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];
glView.hidden=NO;
viewController.view=glView;

[window bringSubviewToFront:glView];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[glView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mainAppLoop) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

With this code touches and motions worked but I don't see anything. (just white screen) :(

I am sure that some of the lines above are not necessary, but I am trying all possible options. What is strange is that no matter if I create my glView or not "loadView" in viewcontroller is not called.
Thank you for help in advance.
Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

while I have connected view outlet in view with controller it started to work... with this:

```
[self becomeFirstResponder]
```